# Random investment returns from a normal distribution (and confidence intervals)

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I work for a financial planning company and what I am trying to do is to project a client’s investment assets forward over several years.  This is easy if we assume a constant return e.g. 7% every year.  However I want to take account of fluctuations of returns and have therefore built in some random returns using excel following a normal distribution.  I then want to show a 95% confidence interval for each return and show the client we are 95% confident that their £100k initial investment will be within £X and £Y in 5 years’ time.  A mini example is as follows. The random returns below are generated by the function `=NORM.INV(RAND(),6.8%,7.5%)` in Excel.

```
Yr 1    Yr 2    Yr 3    Yr 4    Yr 5
4.4%    14.8%   -3.3%   9.9%    4.4%
9.7%    12.3%   11.2%   21.8%   4.6%
-3.2%   14.0%   7.0%    10.7%   -6.5%
5.4%    0.6%    0.0%    7.4%    6.9%
11.7%   6.4%    -6.3%   17.8%   -8.1%
26.9%   -1.4%   2.3%    9.9%    4.5%
4.0%    -1.6%   8.4%    3.8%    1.5%
10.7%   -13.1%  7.1%    9.3%    17.7%
-0.7%   0.8%    -1.1%   0.1%    7.0%
9.6%    1.4%    20.3%   13.2%   -3.4%

Average     7.9%    3.4%    4.6%    10.4%   2.9%  
St Dev      8.3%    8.6%    7.9%    6.3%    7.5%  
CI Upper    13.0%   8.8%    9.4%    14.3%   7.5%  
CI Lower    2.7%    -1.9%   -0.3%   6.5%    -1.8%
```

Investment Amount    £100,000

Future Fund Values

```
         Yr 1        Yr 2        Yr 3        Yr 4          Yr 5
Upper    £112,995    £108,765    £109,434    £114,272      £107,528  
Average £107,850     £103,420    £104,560    £110,390      £102,860  
Lower    £102,705    £98,075     £99,686     £106,508      £98,192
```

The question I have is because we are assuming the upper return and the lower return year on year, are we exaggerating the range? Although the confidence interval for each return is fine, it’s the cumulative effect of this year on year that I’m concerned about. Is what I’m doing statistically correct or can you advise on an alternative method. Any alternative method needs to be able to be iterated easily thousands of times and therefore cannot be too data intensive in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

My first bit of advice would be to learn how to use statisitical software, rather than relying on Excel. `R` is very popular here, but `SAS` is also good as are other programs (they have been discussed many times here).

Then you will want to read up on the literature on this topic. That would include time series analysis in general and financial time series in particular. These are complex topics which will require quite a bit of study.

I would guess that one good approach is to do a lot of simulation, but you would need to decide what to simulate. One approach would be to regard each year as having a return that is randomly drawn from a normal distribution, but with what mean and sd? However, even a non-expert like me is aware that returns on investments may not be normally distributed - the tails are heavier than normal.